# Can't properly login to Jenkins after migrating from Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I need to migrate from Hudson (3.0.1) to Jenkins (1.424.) on the new server with ubuntu 12.04. I decided to install (with apt-get) Jenkins and then just copy config files and reload configuration from disk. 
I copied config.xml to /var/lib/jenkins, I also copied users folder from old installation. Then I made the same setting as were in old installation: "Hudson's own user database" as Security Realm, "Matrix-based security" as Authorization.

Then I reloaded configurations from disk, and now I can't login with my username

> "Invalid login information. Please try again"

I added user jenkins to shadow group (just in case, as suggested [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8709)), but it didn't help.

I can't figure out why Jenkins doesn't want to login me with my old login/password as there are password hashes in each user's config.xml

I can create the same users again via web interface, but there are too many of them.

Jenkins log:

```
Sep 9, 2013 4:17:18 PM hudson.security.AuthenticationProcessingFilter2 

onUnsuccessfulAuthentication
INFO: Login attempt failed
org.acegisecurity.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:197)
    at org.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:47)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:74)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:195)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:368)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:244)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```